# Any way to multithread dpkg-deb

Tags: dpkg, compression, multi-core

Compression for a 500MB deb takes a long time. I still need the compression. Is there anyway to multithread it?

There's pxz, pigz, pbzip2. Is there any way I can get dpkg-deb to use one of these. Or maybe replace the existing non-parallel libraries on my system with these implementations?

I've searched for a while, but it seems that depk-deb only allows a very limited amount of customization for compression options.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

There is [no official support](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=501456#15) in dpkg's libraries at this point. There is however a [patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=501456#27) you can try to use.

Replacing the libraries is not an option because they are not binary compatible. A wrapper library would be needed.